# Do browsers read/store everything in a Javascript file or only the stuff they need?

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, browser

Here's what I'm asking:

Suppose I have on my site

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    someFunction();
    someOtherFunction();
</script>
```

and suppose `someFunction` and `someOtherFunction` are the only functions used on the page and are 2 of 10,000 functions in `global.js`. Clearly the browser would be better off in this situation looking only for those 2 functions in `global.js` and skipping everything that doesn't depend on them, but which of the following ways is actually how the browser parses JS?

1. JS engine takes every function definition it comes across and makes it into machine code and then uses it if it ever needs to
2. JS engine looks for use of functions and then looks for their definitions and builds machine code and uses the function whenever needed (including the use case it found)

Comment: the whole file is parsed

Comment: 1 and 2 appear to be nearly same process ?

Comment: @guest271314 2 implies only the functions used get parsed `looks for use of`

Comment: @JaromandaX What is "use" ? All included text has potential for "use" ? "if it ever needs to" ~ "whenever needed"

Comment: Browsers **interpret** JS code. It isn't compiled to machine commands.

Comment: @PM77-1 well modern runtimes do some JIT work but they won't do it for code that's never used.

Comment: @guest271314 - if you have trouble with the meaning of `use` in the context of the question, perhaps you should open a new question - the two options are quite clearly different

Comment: @JaromandaX No "trouble" , no worries . Only seeking clarity of actual Question by OP.  "if it ever needs to" , "whenever needed" not "quite clearly different" as interpreted here

Comment: @PM77-1 Interesting Question . What is a "machine command" ?  If `js` is contained within `html` document , entire`html` document could be a "machine command" ? , or be "compiled" into a "machine command" ? Similar to a processing instruction within an `html` document; e.g., `php` ?

Comment: @guest271314 - I am not in a hair-splitting mood. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question!

As an answer to your question, **#1** is the most correct, as indeed all functions are parsed by the interpreter during script load, rather than just those referenced by your containing script.

First off, as soon as the include statement executes the **entire JS file** is loaded into the client's browser cache. At that point global.js is **parsed**, **interpreted** and **executed** by your browser's Javascript engine. Any global functions and variables declared in global.js will then be able to be used by the containing script.

It is important to note, however, that no Javascript is ever compiled into machine code, rather it is lexically parsed and *interpreted* according to ECMA standards.

---

For more information on script loading, check out this great resource on html5rocks: [Script Loading](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)

Comment: It isn't converted into machine code though. That would pretty much violate the whole principle of sandboxing.

Comment: Correct, Javascript is an interpreted language. Edit applied.

Comment: how is that #2? #2 says it `looks for use of functions then looks for their definitions` - js engines parse functions regardless if they are `used` or not

Comment: I said it was _most_ correct, although looking back it seems as though #1 is more correct, as indeed all functions are parsed by the interpreter during script load. I think I meant to put #1 instead, thanks for bringing this to my attention:)

Answer (score 0):

1.

> `<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>`

Load entire text source of global.js into memory. Parse and execute any JavaScript code there in the current global environment.

2.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>  someFunction();
>  someOtherFunction();
> </script>
> ```

Look in the current global environment for the function named `someFunction()` and call it. Next look in the current global environment for the function named `someOtherFunction()` and call it. Has absolutely no clue about where or how they were defined.

---

All in all, browsers will take the entire file and parse and execute all of the contained code there up front because that is the design of the language. It will not look forward or "compile" all of the JavaScript code in a page at once.

Comment: _"All in all, browsers will take the entire file and parse and execute all of the contained code there up front "_ Possible exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621475/why-does-window-data-work-and-not-data ?

Comment: @guest271314- If you change the way the script is loaded, the "up front" part could probably be worded better, but once the script has loaded then it will immediately parse and execute. Setting the script to defer for example would cause the file to be loaded with some delay.

Comment: _"and execute all of the contained code"_ is portion that noticed , here . Not commenting whether that is correct or not , only that there may be exceptions to an absolute synchronous , or perceived synchronous process

Comment: They aren't really exceptions. It is synchronous. Purposefully delaying that process would be then a feature. Similar to a script loading from ajax for example.